# Replacing ? from document.location.search

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which i am using document.location.search in it.. I want to replace the ? with an &.. How i can do that please?

```
<script language="javascript">
        document.write("<a href='http://www.gfi.com/downloads/downloads.aspx?pid=fax&lid=en" + document.location.search + "'><img src='http://images.gfi.com/download-imagery/button-download.png' border='0'></a>");
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(document.location.search).replace("?","&");
```

so:

```
document.write("<a href='http://www.gfi.com/downloads/downloads.aspx?pid=fax&lid=en" + (document.location.search).replace("?","&") + "'><img src='http://images.gfi.com/download-imagery/button-download.png' border='0'></a>");
```

Comment: just to highlight the separation between the two elements in the code so its easier for the OP to see whats happening